# Convertendo dois selects MySQL para um

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou com uma pequena dúvida sobre o MySQL.

Possuo a seguinte consulta MySQL:

```php
sq1 = mysqli($conexao,"select * from tabela1");
$tr1 = mysqli_num_rows($sq1);
```

Daí então faço o famoso laço:

```php
for ($i=0;$i<$tr1;$i++)
{ 
$registro1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sq1);
$codigo1   = registro1['tabela1_codigo'];
```

A partir do `codigo1`, eu faço uma nova consulta para buscar dados na `tabela2`:

```php
sq2 = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from tabela2 where 
tabela2_estrangeira='$codigo1'");

sq2 = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from tabela3 where 
tabela3_estrangeira='$codigo1'");

// faço um outro `for` aqui para listar os dados da tabela2:

// faço um outro `for` aqui para listar os dados da tabela3:
 ...

}
```

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como que posso otimizar essas consultas, usando apenas um `select`?

Comment: E de ponde você está trazendo o primeiro código, é um GET?

Answer (score 7):

Pode fazer algo assim:

```
$sql = 'select T1.* from tabela1 as T1
 LEFT JOIN tabela2 AS T2 ON T2.tabela2_estrangeira = T1.tabela1_codigo';
```

Fiz algo genérico pois o JOIN pode ser a direita `RIGHT JOIN` ou também pode querer usar `INNER` ou `OUTER`.

Por fim, para não complicar muito, use `LEFT JOIN` conforme exemplo acima.

Esteja atento que no exemplo apliquei alias.

A tabela1 usa **T1** e a segunda tabela usa **T2**.

Para aceder as colunas da tabela1, faça `T1.nome_da_caluna`

ex: `T1.tabela1_codigo`

Comment: Só para complementar, aqui está a diferença dos "JOIN": [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Comment: Olá Daniel, fiz como sugeriu. Editei minha pergunta com uma nova dúvida.

Comment: Evite múltiplas perguntas. Se resolveu o problema inicial pode apenas  marcar como resolvido. Para novas dúvidas abra uma nova pergunta. Leia esse guia para entender o funcionamento básico do StackOverflow http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: entendido. farei isso. obgd.

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, como você não está injetando código nenhum, não vejo a necessidade de passar uma variável correndo risco de sql injection a toa.

```
/* 
  Isso "t1.*,t2.*,t3.*" é o mesmo que isso "*",
  mas se você, de repente, quiser separar os valores,
  basta criar um alias, tipo: t1.nome as nom_tabela1, t2.nome as nom_tabela2
*/
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,
           'SELECT t1.*,t2.*,t3.*
            FROM tabela1 t1
            LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2
            on(t1.tabela1_codigo=t2.tabela2_estrangeira)
            LEFT JOIN tabela3 t3
            on(t2.tabela2_estrangeira=t3.tabela3_estrangeira)
            WHERE 1');
```