# Como fazer ordenações distintas em tabelas com Left Join?

Tags: mysql

Preciso da seguinte ajuda de vocês.

Primeiramente, vejam abaixo a minha consulta atual:

```
sq1 = mysqli($conexao,"select * from tabela1 TBL1 left join tabela2 TBL2 ON
         TBL1.codigo=TBL2.codigoestrangeiro LEFT JOIN tabela3 TBL3 ON
         TBL2.codigo=TBL3.codigoestrangeiro
         group by TBL1.codigo order by TBL1.codigo desc");
```

A tabela 2 e tabela 3 podem conter *n* registros vinculados à tabela 1.
Neste caso, como faço para chamar por essas informações?

E como faço para ordenar as informações de maneira personalizada, ou seja, a tabela 2 deverá ser exibida por ordem de nome, e a tabela 3 por data.

Comment: relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143668/convertendo-dois-selects-mysql-para-um

Comment: Novamente, conforme comentei na outra pergunta, evite múltiplas perguntas numa só. Lei o guia de uso do site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @DanielOmine, mesmo que seja duas pergunta, não seria muito criativo criar outra pergunta somente para sabe como ordenar uma consulta.

Comment: Leia o guia de uso do site, por favor.

Comment: @Luis, seu select esta quase certo, só não sei qual a necessidade de usar o group by?

Comment: para ordenar: `order by TBL1.codigo desc, TBL2.nome ASC, TBL3.data ASC`

Comment: para `n` registros use `left join`, para pegar registros únicos, use `inner join`. **Obs:** o `group by`, irá agrupar os registros, sendo assim, não irá trazer todas as relações, filtrando os demais registros, somente aparecerá "o primeiro registro que encontrar" para cada código.

Comment: Olá, Marco, se eu não utilizar o group by, ele irá repetir registros de um mesmo código da tabela 1. Se a tabela 2 tiver 3 registros, ele iria mostrar o codigo da tabela 1 repetido 3 vezes.

Comment: Entendi Daniel, desculpe mais uma vez.